# What's the number 2, 1.84, 2.35 meaning in this news report?

Tags: stocks

I came across a entry [here](http://www.marketsinsider.com/broker-recommendations-fireeye-inc-ebay-inc/331932/).

I am quite interested what does the numbers in it means. I have marked them bold as quoted below:

> Fireeye Inc (NASDAQ:FEYE) has received a buy rating, according to the
>   latest rank of **2** from research firm, Zacks. The counter could manage
>   an average rating of **1.84** from 19 analysts.
>
> ...
>
> As many as 29 brokerage firms have rated Ebay Inc (NASDAQ:EBAY) at
>   **2.35**. Research Analysts at Zacks have ranked the company at **3**...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Zacks Site](http://b7d61a7c6b8c307bf531-a92a66b9587e2a0aa805bd4e70b98407.r95.cf2.rackcdn.com/pdf/zacks_billion_dollar_secret.pdf) this image answers the question.

[image]

The above is meant as an explanation of the numbering system, as described by Zacks, not a personal endorsement or comment of any kind regarding the system success.

Comment: Of course, as with all models, the fact that someone publishes it -- even if it has worked pretty well so far -- is not proof that it's correct. It could go wonky tomorrow. Caveat lector, caveat investor.

Comment: @keshlam: The fact that someone publishes may make it go wonky, if enough people believe in the chart...

Comment: This answer addresses the "2" and "3", but not the "rating of 1.84 from 19 analysts" or "29 brokerage firms... at 2.35".

Comment: The non-integer results are averages of those ratings. You rate a company "1" and I rate "2." The average is 1.5. An individual brokerage house isn't offering a 1.84 rating.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes, that is what one would guess from a non-integer number in this case, but as Zacks is "a proprietary stock rating model" wouldn't any company using that model be expected to come up with the same result? Or is there simply a conversion of a firm's "buy" rating to a "2"?

Comment: I believe that "strong buy" "buy" "hold" "sell" and "strong sell" correspond to the numbers. Zack just claims to have a proprietary way to determine their number. I have my own proprietary way.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I would like to subscribe to your newsletter...